# CMakelist.txt to include external headers and files in a folder (odeint in boost)

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I downloaded a zip file to solve ODE (odeint in boost) containing headers and files for my C++ project. Can I use it directly without download the whole boost packages?

My question is how to use it.

I added a line in the `CMakeLists.txt` file (shown below), and I am able to find the key header file `odeint.hpp`. But the `odeint.hpp` contains other header files, such as `config.hpp` in a subdirectory (shown in picture). Now the compiler can't find other header files such as `config.hpp` etc. What should I do?

(The package that I downloaded is from http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/downloads.html for solving ODEs.)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(myProjects)

# I added this line below
include_directories("D:/myProjects/odeint/include")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp test.h test.cpp)
add_executable(myProjects ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use CMake? How is ODEint usually built? You should never add abosulte paths in a CMakeLists.txt. If you want to use CMake, learn some CMake with a book or tutorial and try again. We won't teach, we help people with actual questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need the boost libraries. I would suggest to only use the boost libraries and use odeint from there.

Simply download and extract it. Then, you can easily use CMake. Just add

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "/path/to/boost")
find_package(Boost)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

to your CMakeLists.txt